# Fuzzy search in Azure SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, fuzzy-search

In the project I work we have the necessity to use some kind of fuzzy search to fill an autocomplete field. This autocomplete field must show some information as the user type inside.

I'm using Azure SQL database, and I found out that it's not possible to use Master Data Services. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/master-data-services-installation-and-configuration?view=sql-server-2017)

I've already googled some solutions, and I've found something related to Levenstein fuzzy search, but the implementations I've found did not fit well in my scenario.

I'm very newbie at fuzzy searches, plz, could you suggest any actual implementation of fuzzy search in T-SQL.

Comment: `some kind of fuzzy search` the kind of search you want matters a lot. Prefix searches are essentially a `LIKE 'prefix%'` that can take advantage of indexes. Searching anywhere in the string can't use any indexes. Using the edit distance (eg the Levenshtein algorithm) is useful for *autocorrect* searches. SQL Server can't help in these cases

Comment: If you want to do a prefix search, just use a `LIKE 'prefix%'`. In other cases it's best to use a search engine, eg Elasticsearch or the managed Azure Search service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers) documentation for step-by-step instructions on how to connect to and index an Azure SQL Database content using Azure Search indexers.

After that you can use Azure Search API to perform a fuzzy search.

```
https://{yourSite}.search.windows.net/indexes/{yourIndex}/docs?search={fieldToSearch}:{lookupValue}~&queryType=Full?api-version=2015-02-28&suggesterName=default&queryType=full&search=California~
```

You need to specify querytype=full and the tilde after the character/word that you want to execute fuzzy searches on.